# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider in a Kotlin project for Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, build.gradle

I created a console application for Windows in Kotlin.
In that app, I want to send files to an AWS S3 bucket.

For that purpose, I initiate my S3 client like the following:

```
// credentials provider :
val classpathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider = ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("AWSCredentials.properties")

// S3 client :
val amazonS3: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion("eu-central-1")
    .withCredentials(classpathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider)
    .build()
```

And here are all the imports in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opensdk:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-apigatewayv2:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:1.12.58'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3control:1.12.58'
```

The project compiles without any error, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider
```

which I don't understand, since I did the same in another Java Swing project, and it works fine.

Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To work with Kotlin and AWS Services such as Amazon S3, you should consider using the **AWS SDK for Kotlin**. This is a newer SDK built for Kotlin developers. You are currently using the *AWS SDK for Java V1*. If you are using Java, then you should move from V1 to [Java V2](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2).

To learn how to get started with the **AWS SDK for Kotlin**, see this topic:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-kotlin/blob/main/docs/GettingStarted.md

To work with Amazon S3 and Kotlin, refer to the code examples in [Github here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/.kotlin_alpha/services/s3).

To upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket using the Kotlin SDK, use this code:

```
package com.kotlin.s3

// snippet-start:[s3.kotlin.s3_object_upload.import]
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.S3Client
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.s3.model.S3Exception
import aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.content.ByteStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.IOException
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
// snippet-end:[s3.kotlin.s3_object_upload.import]

/**
To run this Kotlin code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment,
including your credentials.
For information, see this documentation topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
 */
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val usage = """
    Usage:
        <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath>
    Where:
        bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.
        objectKey - the object to upload (for example, book.pdf).
        objectPath - the path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf).
    """

   if (args.size != 3) {
       println(usage)
       exitProcess(0)
   }

    val bucketName = args[0]
    val objectKey = args[1]
    val objectPath = args[2]
    val s3Client = S3Client { region = "us-east-1" }
    putS3Object(s3Client, bucketName, objectKey, objectPath)
    s3Client.close()
}

// snippet-start:[s3.kotlin.s3_object_upload.main]
suspend fun putS3Object(
        s3Client: S3Client,
        bucketName: String,
        objectKey: String,
        objectPath: String
    ){

        try {
            val metadataVal = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
            metadataVal["myVal"] = "test"

            val putOb = PutObjectRequest {
                bucket = bucketName
                key = objectKey
                metadata = metadataVal
                this.body = ByteStream.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath))
            }

            val response =s3Client.putObject(putOb)
            println("Tag information is ${response.eTag}")

        } catch (e: S3Exception) {
            println(e.message)
            s3Client.close()
            exitProcess(0)
        }
    }

    fun getObjectFile(filePath: String): ByteArray {
        var fileInputStream: FileInputStream? = null
        lateinit var bytesArray: ByteArray
        try {

            val file = File(filePath)
            bytesArray = ByteArray(file.length().toInt())
            fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray)

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println(e.message)
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    println(e.message)
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray
    }
```

**NOTE** that all examples assume that your creds are located in a file named **credentials** as explained here:

[Setting the default credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks! I'll check that out.

Comment: Its new - but is best practice for Kotlin Developers as it supports Kotlin concepts like https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html

Comment: OK so I found out that the problem came from a bad project structure in my Intellij project. Now it works!

Comment: If you want to write a lot of Kotlin code, Amazon recommends moving to the Kotlin SDK